# What does "launch forth" mean in this context? (From the book, Life of Pi)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from the book, Life of Pi.

> He's a small, slim man. Mild fall weather, yet puts on a big winter parka with  fur-lined hood for the walk to the diner. Expressive face. Speaks quickly, hands flitting about. No small talk. He **launches forth.**

I already saw the dictionary definition of it, which is "To begin or set out on a journey or trip" or "To issue, propel, or project something forward with force".

But I still can't quite grasp what it exactly means here.

Does it imply that the man says "without any hesitation" and "goes straight into whatever he wants to say"?

Comment: We don't know exactly without the sentences which follow your quotation.  But essentially it means "he starts something in a vigorous manner".

Comment: That's the end of the passage/chapter and there's no additional context ;(. That's why I was more confused. but thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's a literary mechanism to make you curious.  From this little context I'd read it as "he starts speaking", and "launch" means emphatically or vigorously.  "Forth" is faintly archaic, used idiomatically to mean "as if giving a sermon".

Comment: @jonathanjo Are you joking perhaps?  It is clearly wrong but faintly amusing to claim the meaning of “forth” has anything directly to do with “a sermon”.  It means “forward” or “onward” and is indeed outdated or archaic in most contexts. But, for example, if I say, “The room was pitch black but I bravely ventured forth.” Do you really think that I move into the room “as if giving a sermon”? How is the prototypical sermon even supposed to be given if this is some sort of analogy?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie At least in the UK, "to hold forth" has that meaning, and that is how I understood the literary sense "to launch forth" in this passage, following a description of how he speaks -- accepting fully that it might have many other meanings which might make more sense with more context.  OED gives "**to hold forth** 4. intransitive.  To preach; to speak publicly, discourse, harangue. (Usually somewhat contemptuous.)"

Comment: @jonathanjo  I take this as meaning that you agree with me. You were mistakenly referring to the combination “hold forth”, since this is where you usually expect to find “forth”. You made an understandable error by imbuing “forth”, on its own, with a meaning that is only relevant to “hold forth”, in combination. The meanings and nuances here, by the way, seem to be the same in both Britain and Australia (as the usage dates back to a time when correct formal Australian usage was standard British usage) although the expression “hold forth” is probably now rarer here than the UK.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie thanks for your comment, but I don't agree with you.  The book covers many things with many overlapping readings.  My reading of it is that "He launches forth." means "He starts" with echos of many other things.  Perhaps he starts walking, perhaps he starts speaking.  It might mean simply "He goes walking", or "He starts speaking" and it might have some overtones of "He launches into a rant and holds forth for an hour".  The ambiguities of the original mean I would definitely say this is a question for Literature stack exchange more than ELL.

Comment: @jonathanjo. I disagree about Literature Stack - this is about the meaning transmitted by the words as they are (relatively) commonly used.  But in other respects I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the final sentence of the short chapter,

> He launches forth.

on the face of it, simply means, “He sets off.”, “He starts forward.” However, the word choice here adds considerably more to the meaning.

Using the dramatic “launches” rather than a simpler synonym like “starts” or “begins” gives the sense that it is a significant undertaking that is beginning. Similarly, using the almost archaic word “forth” instead of its simpler counterparts, lends a sense of grandeur and supports the drama.

Answer (score 1):

**He launches forth.** means simply "He starts forward".

It has many possible meanings and echoes beyond that, probably better suited to Literature stack exchange than here.  You will see in comments disagreement about what overtones are implied and what exactly was started.